# Weird gap in LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I'm not very experienced with `LazyVGrid`. What is this weird gap between the 1:45 and 2:00 buttons, and how can I get rid of it?

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  
  let dates: [Date] = (0...34).compactMap { interval -> Date? in
    var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())
    components.hour = 7
    components.minute = 30
    
    guard var date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { return nil }
    
    date.addTimeInterval(Double(900 * interval))
    
    if Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date) == 12 {
      date.addTimeInterval(3600)
    }
    
    return date
  }
  
  func text(for date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem.init(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil), count: 3)) {
      ForEach(dates, id: \.self) { date in
        Button {
          
        } label: {
          Capsule()
            .overlay {
              Text(text(for: date))
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(height: 44)
        }
      }
    }.padding()
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView().frame(width: 400, height: 800).padding())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your logic for skipping the 12 o'clock hour time slots is resulting in 4 duplicate dates. You need a collection with only unique values.

In the `dates` property initializer, replace the line:

```swift
date.addTimeInterval(3600)
```

with:

```swift
return nil
```

This will eliminate the 4 12 o'clock time slots and avoid any duplicate dates which in turn removes the gap in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have these gaps is because you have multiple dates the same. The `ForEach` loop requires unique items for it to work.

One way to avoid this is to create a unique object for each date, such as shown in the example code:

```
// --- here
struct DateItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var date: Date
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // --- here
    let dates: [DateItem] = (0...34).compactMap { interval -> DateItem? in
        var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())
        components.hour = 7
        components.minute = 30
        
        guard var date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { return nil }
        
        date.addTimeInterval(Double(900 * interval))
        
        if Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date) == 12 {
            date.addTimeInterval(3600)
        }
        
        return DateItem(date: date) // <--- here
    }
    
    func text(for date: Date) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem.init(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil), count: 3)) {
            ForEach(dates) { date in  // <--- here
                Button {
                    // ...
                } label: {
                    Capsule()
                        .overlay {
                            Text(text(for: date.date))  // <--- here
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(height: 44)
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this result in showing duplicate dates in the grid instead of skipping the undesired times?

Comment: Good point, use what you suggested `return nil`.
 The point with my approach is that it is more general,
 any other dates that are the same will be displayed (unless more logic is used) but importantly
 will avoid trippping the `ForEach` loop.